# Windows batch file to list folders that have a specific file in them

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to create a file that has a list of directories that have a specific file name in them.

Let's say I'm trying to find directories that have a file named `*.joe` in them.  I initially tried just a simple `dir /ad *.joe > dir_list.txt` , but it searches the directory names for `*.joe`, so no go.

Then I concluded that a for loop was probably my best bet.  I started with

```
for /d /r %a in ('dir *.joe /b') do @echo %a >> dir_list.txt
```

and it looked like it wasn't executing the dir command.  I added the "usebackq", but that seems to only work for the /F command extension.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Since "`dir /s /b file_name`" doesn't cut it, how about the following

```
for /d /r %a in (*) do  @if exist %a\*.scr (echo %a)
```

It would appear that inside a batch file the only thing that needs to be esaped is the %a giving

```
for /d /r %%a in (*) do  @if exist %%a\*.scr (echo %%a)
```

Comment: Not *exactly* what he's looking for, but +1 because it's by far the easiest solution to the problem. A simple REPLACE("file_name", "") afterwards would give you the desired output - any way to do that in a BAT file?

Comment: I was using that before I realized I needed just directory names and not file names; that's when I began experimenting with the dir /ad and I just spiraled downhill from there...

Comment: @Lee: Thanks for shaing your downhill spriral with me ;) Hopefully my edit above brings it to an end.

Comment: Whoa.  Okay, it works from a command prompt, but not from within a batch file.  ???  I didn't specify that in my original question (sorry about that) - I get a "(echo was unexpected at this time." error.  Very elegant, though - kudos to you, especially if it can work in a batch file.

Comment: Oh, and for anybody else reading this - if you add a path before the %%a part, you can specify at what point the script begins to search recursively.  Very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Save this to `search.bat` or (something else you can remember)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set last=?

if "%1" EQU "" goto usage

for /f %%I in ('dir /s /b /o:n /a-d "%1"') do (
  if !last! NEQ %%~dpI ( 
    set last=%%~dpI
    echo !last!
  )
)
goto end

:usage
echo Please give search parameter.

:end
```

and use as follows:

```
search.bat *.joe >dir_list.txt
```

Note that it searches within the current path context. You might want to add the `.bat` to a location that is in the `PATH`, so you can call it from any location.

Comment: @Lee: It's a `for` loop over every line the `dir` command returns, this part should be clear. Then it uses the `last` variable to compare every line with the one before. When they differ, it prints the line. This way only the unique lines are printed. Read `for /?` to find out what `%~dpI` means. Search StackOverflow or Google for what `EnableDelayedExpansion` means. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will print the directory and the file name, may or may not be helpful to you:

```
dir /b /s | findstr "\.joe"
```

`findstr` uses a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

`dir /s/b *.joe >> dir_list.txt` and then a skript in e.g. gawk to get rid of the filenames after the dirnames